# Numbers from string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
candy 5.5, icecream 3.4, something valuable 1,185.5*2
```

Im using `.` and `,` for separators specifically.
im need to get from this string

> var sum = 5.5 + 3.4 + 1185.5*2

Comment: I think something is very wrong if you need to parse a string like that.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you want to handle the operators (such as *, /). Do you also need to extract them as well?

Comment: >ThiefMaster  May be he want to extract something from a website or text.

Comment: im dont wanna extract it, such an expression as 7*7 can be extracted as 49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choice would be this:

```
var buildSumString = function(testString) {
    rx=/(\d[\d\.\*]*)/g
    return 'var sum = ' + testString.match(rx).join(' + ');
};

var testString = "candy 5.5, icecream 3.4, something valuable 1,185.5*2";
var rebuiltString = buildSumString(testString);
```

The only assumption to make here is that there will be no white space in your number strings, though that can be easily added.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure this could be implemented using regular expressions

Using a pattern like

```
(?:([0-9.,*]+).*?)?
```

to find all occurrences (in java-script i think it is the g modifier) and then just some standard processing to remove all of the commas and then add the fields as usual

If you haven't used regular expressions before W3schools is usually a good place to start
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Sorry i cant give anything more specific but i haven't used javascript enough

Answer (score 1):

Poor design because you have a comma as a separator and also as a part of a number.

My advice is to make two passes through the string. First look for , between two digits followed by 3 digits, and delete the commas. Regular expresssions might be useful here. On the swecond pas split the string on the commas, then on each part scan from the right to the first space character to break off the numeric parts.

Build a string by adding plus signs, and then use `eval` to do the calculation. That will take care of any extra multiply operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an expression string from your string like this[*]:

```
 var str = 'candy 5.5, icecream 3.4, something valuable 1,185.5*2'
   , sum = str.replace(/[a-z]+|,\s+/gi,'').trim().split(/\s+/).join(' + ');
```

and `eval` it. Still, you may want to think about other ideas to handle this (using a better separator in the initial string, a way to avoid eval ([considered evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)) etc.)

[*] `trim` being

```
String.prototype.trim = function(){
 return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
}
```